# DOM access to different elements

Tags: javascript, dom

I’m trying to learn how to get to different levels of the DOM with javaScript, once I’ve made an initial entry point. For example, if I want to access the following div element, I would target its attribute:

```
var divContent =  document.getElementById(‘box_1’);
```

How would I access the li tags? Ultimately, I want to write an event handler that will populate the li tags, but I first need to know how to access them via the ID attribute for the div.

```
<div id="box_1">
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I hope this helps. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp

Comment: There’s a difference between `‘’` and `''`. Use the correct quote marks.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess what: you can get the elements by `TagName`, having your id as the parent node. Cool, han?

```
var parent = document.getElementById('box_1'),
    children = parent.getElementsByTagName('li');
    // gets all children of parent
```

Now you just need to iterate over child 'li' nodes

```
var i, e;
for (i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
    e = children[i];
    //do magic with e
}
```

Comment: Just a typo, chill out.

Comment: This is great! I will need to populate each li with different content so I knew I needed to set up some kind of loop.

Comment: Glad it help. Can you upvote me too? Haters had me down voted. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to grab all of the `li` elements that are children of a certain parent?

```
children = document.querySelectorAll('#box_1 li');
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I like this approach too because it combines the ID and nested elements in one statement.